# Merge tables in R using like

Tags: r, sql-like, sqldf

I have two tables which I am trying to merge using the like function.

I want to join `Table1` to `Table2` and if `Field1 contains Field11` then append `Field12` to `Table1` in the output. The output should look like that in `Table3`
[Data Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1PUH.jpg)

I tried using the sqldf function but didn't have much success

```
D2 = sqldf("select a.*, b.Field12
             from Table1 a left join Table2 b
              on a.Field1 like "%[b.Field11]+%"
             ")
```

Answer (score 1):

I am still to see an R function that can do fuzzy joins with e.g. a like operator or between, while it is quite common in SQL.
That you use sqldf seems to be a good candidate for a solution.

The issue I see, in lack of a proper minimal working example, is that your `like` criteria is wrong (and the inevitable error message your line would produce). sqldf relies on the SQLite database format, so that is where you should seek for documentation.

Short answer: Try using

```
D2 = sqldf("select a.*, b.Field12 from Table1 a left join Table2 b on a.Field1 like '%' || [b.Field11] || '%' ;")
```